# How to switch off Description column in Django Rest Framework Documentation?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to switch off `Description` column in Django Rest Framework Documentation? As you can see on the screenshot below there is a column `Description`. It is obvious what `username` and `password` mean, so I don't need to add more information, however empty cells don't look well. I would like to switch off it only for this method, because for instance in others I would like to have descriptions. Any ideas how can I do this? [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this at the moment, since that 'Description' column is set at template level. See this [template](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/docs/link.html).

To be able to do this in a nicer way you need to customize rest_framework/docs/link.html, maybe have a template tag to check for a custom flag in here:

```
{% elif link.fields|with_location:'form' %}
<h4>Request Body</h4>
<p>The request body should be a <code>"{{ link.encoding }}"</code> encoded object, containing the following&nbsp;items.</p>
<table class="parameters table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Parameter</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for field in link.fields|with_location:'form' %}
        <tr><td class="parameter-name"><code>{{ field.name }}</code>{% if field.required %} <span class="label label-warning">required</span>{% endif %}</td><td>{% if field.schema.description %}{{ field.schema.description }}{% endif %}</td></tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

But I think this is too much to consider just to have that column removed.